# objdump on machine code with blocks of zeros doesn't show all the bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, objdump

May I know why I don't see 15 bytes of 0x00 in the assembly code which is shown by objdump?

```
$ cat test.c 
void main()
{
   __asm__(".byte 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00");
}
$ gcc -masm=intel -g -c test.c 
$ objdump -d -M intel -S test.o 

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
void main()
{
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    ...
  10:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
  12:   00 5d c3                add    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x3d],bl
$
```

Comment: Try adding the `-z` option to objdump which should disassemble zeroes. THe `...` is where zeroes would be

Answer (score 1):

You want [objdump's `-z` option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html):

> `-z`
>   `--disassemble-zeroes`
>    Normally the disassembly output
>   will skip blocks of zeroes.  This option directs the disassembler to
>   disassemble those blocks, just like any other data.

Answer (score 0):

The other way if you familiar with [radare2](https://radare.org)

```
% gcc -masm=intel -g -c test.c -o test
% r2 -AA mc                       
Warning: run r2 with -e io.cache=true to fix relocations in disassembly
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Check for objc references
[x] Check for vtables
[x] Type matching analysis for all functions (aaft)
[x] Propagate noreturn information
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
[x] Finding function preludes
[x] Enable constraint types analysis for variables
-- How good is your C? 
[0x08000034]> afl
0x08000034    1 23           sym.main
[0x08000034]> pdf @ sym.main
           ;-- section..text:
           ;-- .text:
           ;-- eip:
┌ 23: int sym.main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
│           0x08000034      55             push ebp                    ; [01] -r-x section size 21 named .text
│           0x08000035      89e5           mov ebp, esp
│           0x08000037      0000           add byte [eax], al
│           0x08000039      0000           add byte [eax], al
│           0x0800003b      0000           add byte [eax], al
│           0x0800003d      0000           add byte [eax], al
│           0x0800003f      0000           add byte [eax], al
│           0x08000041      0000           add byte [eax], al
│           0x08000043      0000           add byte [eax], al
└           0x08000045  ~   00905dc3ffff   add byte [eax - 0x3ca3], dl
│           ;-- section..data:
│           ;-- section..bss:
│           ;-- section..debug_info:
│           ;-- .data:
│           ;-- .bss:
│           ;-- .debug_info:
..
[0x08000034]>
```